Flutter- Pick contact from from default contact app
I want to pick a contact from the mobile default contact app. I have searched lots of things but getting the same response from everyone, first, fetch the contact list in our application then pick the contact. but I don't want to fetch the contact list. I want to implement like when we pick the image, video, file, etc directly from the mobile default app.

This package can help you to achieve your goal. It supports picking a single contact in both Android/iOS.
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_contact_picker
